# El punto de interrupcion no se activara actualmente. No se ha cargado ningun simbolo para este formulario, proyecto blazor

Tags: depuración

ya hice todo a mi proyecto y no puedo, inicio con google chrome y se cae sin abrir el proyecto, al pasarlo a mozilla si me abre y carga pero no puedo depurar, ya intente eliminar el archivo .pdb, tambien desactive la opcion "Optimizar código" es en visual studio 2022
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]